# Combine Multiple Arrays - based on number?

Tags: php, arrays, merge

It seems easy, but can't figure out how to do this.  The current array data is listed by date and amount by date, so I need to combine all the dates: day, month, 6 month, 1 year.  I need to arrange the array data to look like the second array below.

```
    array
      0 => enter code here
        array
          '1_day' => int 37
      1 => 
        array
          '30_day' => int 3275
      2 => 
        array
          '180_day' => int 3908
      3 => 
        array
          '1_year' => int 6933
      4 => 
        array
          'date' => string '2013-02-13' (length=10)
      5 => 
        array
          '1_day' => int 46
      6 => 
        array
          '30_day' => int 3134
      7 => 
        array
          '180_day' => int 3764
      8 => 
        array
          '1_year' => int 6820
      9 => 
        array
          'date' => string '2013-02-12' (length=10)
      10 => 
        array
          '1_day' => int 61
      11 => 
        array
          '30_day' => int 3127
      12 => 
        array
          '180_day' => int 3750
      13 => 
        array
          '1_year' => int 6807
      14 => 
        array
          'date' => string '2013-02-11' (length=10)
```

```
    array
      0 => 
          '1_day' => int 37
          '30_day' => int 3275
          '180_day' => int 3908
          '1_year' => int 6933
          'date' => string '2013-02-13' (length=10)
      1 => 
          '1_day' => int 46
          '30_day' => int 3134
          '180_day' => int 3764
          '1_year' => int 6820
          'date' => string '2013-02-12' (length=10)
      2 => 
          '1_day' => int 61
          '30_day' => int 3127
          '180_day' => int 3750
          '1_year' => int 6807
          'date' => string '2013-02-11' (length=10)
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), please.

Comment: What do you mean combine? do you want all the 1_day values to be a sum, or an array of ints?

Comment: OK, you have an array. Do you have a question too? *Edit: OK, question is clear now*

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the problem?

Comment: @ant-C First question here, please read what to do [when you get answers](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested, but this should get you close:

```
<?php

$result = array();

for ($i = 0; $i <= count($array); $i++)
{
    if ($array[$i] == 'date')
    {
        $result[] = array(
            '1_day'    => $array[$i-4],
            '30_day'   => $array[$i-3],
            '180_day'  => $array[$i-2],
            '1_year'   => $array[$i-1],
            'date'     => $array[$i],
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch!!  This seemed way too easy to have  such trouble with lol.  I made some changes but basically this worked like a charm.

Comment: Glad I could help - if you're satisfied with this answer, don't forget to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this one....

$result = array();     
 $i = 0;
foreach($data as $key => $d) 
{
    $result[$i]['1_day'] = $data[$key]['1_day'];
    $result[$i]['30_day'] = $data[$key+1]['30_day'];
    $result[$i]['180_day'] = $data[$key+2]['180_day'];
    $result[$i]['1_year'] = $data[$key+3]['1_year'];
    $result[$i]['date'] = $data[$key+4]['date'];
    $key = $key+5;
    $i++;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

```
<?php

$count = count($inArray);

//In place subarray merger, by this you don't have to modify keys every time they change.
//Constraint: A sub-array at every index.

for ($idx =0, $jdx =0; $idx < $count; $idx +=5, $jdx++) {
    $inArray[$jdx] = array_merge($inArray[$idx],
                                $inArray[$idx +1],
                                $inArray[$idx +2],
                                $inArray[$idx +3],
                                $inArray[$idx +4]);
}

array_splice ($inArray, $count/5);

/* OR into another array */

for ($idx =0, $jdx =0; $idx < $count; $idx +=5, $jdx++) {
    $newArray[$jdx] = array_merge($inArray[$idx],
                                $inArray[$idx +1],
                                $inArray[$idx +2],
                                $inArray[$idx +3],
                                $inArray[$idx +4]);
}

?>
```

Comment: This is more what I was trying to figure out originally using array_merge.  I will try this thanks!